# how to search wordpress database for slug names

Tags: slug, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to rename one of my pages to 2017 and the slug to 2017 as well.  When i click save the slug is renamed to 2017-2.  To me this means something else is using this slug, but i'm not sure how to find what is using it.

I tried going to my phpmyadmin and doing a database search for 2017, but nothing shows up there besides 2017 being a larger part of a number (ie 30382017)

I've also tried going to that page www.example.com/2017 and get a page not found error.

is there a way to find out what may be using this and why i can't rename to just 2017?

Comment: Did you check the wp_terms table? `SELECT * FROM wp_terms w where slug like '2017%';` Could you please edit your question to show the SQL that you've already tried? I used `SELECT * FROM wp_posts w where post_name like '2017%';` for posts.

Comment: that returned a 0 result.  the search i did was click the search tab in phpmy admin, entered 2017 in the search field, chose all tables and clicked search.  I didnt use SQL manually.

Comment: definitely not a duplicate on my part, but that did answer the question.  Thanks!